# Slicing in glom?

Tags: python, glom

**In short:**
How can I slice in glom? That is, being able to specify that I want to extract from several indices (e.g. `y = x[(2, 5, 11)]`), not just a single one (e.g. `y = x[2]`).

**Simple example**: Say I have this data:

```py
d = {'_result': [[1, 'a'], [2, 'b'], [3, 'c']]}
```

To extract a named zip(*) of the "_result" list of lists, I could do this:

```py
from glom import Spec
extract = Spec(('_result', 
                  lambda x: list(zip(*x)), 
                  lambda x: {'x': x[0], 'y': x[1]})).glom
```

And I'd get what I want:

```py
>>> extract(d)
{'x': (1, 2, 3), 'y': ('a', 'b', 'c')}
```

But I'd like to be able to do something like...

```py
extract = Spec(('_result', {'x': '*.0', 'y': '*.1'})).glom
```

or

```py
extract = Spec(('_result', {'x': '[:].0', 'y': '[:].1'})).glom
```

**An even more advanced wish...**

I could imagine such syntactic sugar as being able to specify paths like

```py
"a.[2:3, -5:].{'foo', 'bar'}.name"
```

could come in handy. Even (and possibly safer) if it were by an explicit glom.Path definition, such as

```py
from glom import Path
path = Path('a', 
            ((slice(2, 3, None), slice(-5, None, None)),), 
            {'foo', 'bar'},
            'name')
```

Where in my (probably not best choice) mini-language, the `{'foo', 'bar'}` means we're extracting the values for both of those keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> d = [[1, 'a'], [2, 'b'], [3, 'c']]
>>> glom(d, {'x': [T[0]], 'y': [T[1]]})
{'x': [1, 2, 3], 'y': ['a', 'b', 'c']}
```

glom co-creator here :-)

[T](https://glom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#glom.T) has got you covered. Strings are parsed and converted into [Path](https://glom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#glom.Path) instances.  Paths are convenient and Ts are precise.

If you want to mix them together, you can either join them with a tuple or use the explicit Path constructor.

```
>>> Path('a.b', T[1:3])
Path('a.b', T[slice(1, 3, None)])
```